# NumPy loadtxt data type

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to load a data set that looks like this:

```
Algeria,73.131000,6406.8166213983,0.1
Angola,51.093000,5519.1831786593,2
Argentina,75.901000,15741.0457726686,0.5
Armenia,74.241000,4748.9285847709,0.1
```

etc. At the end, I will need only columns 1 and 2. I won't need country names and the last column. Essentially, I need to extract two matrices with dimensions nx1. I know that I need to specify the data type:

```
data=np.loadtxt('file.txt',delimiter=',',dtype=[('f0',str),('f1',float),('f2',float),('f3',float)])
```

However, this produces a list of tuples,

```
array([('', 73.131, 6406.8166213983, 0.1),
   ('', 51.093, 5519.1831786593, 2.0),`
```

instead of

```
array(['',73.131,6406.8166213983,0.1],
      ['',51.093, 5519.1831786593, 2.0],
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: FWIW, your output is not a list of tuples, but a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).  Your desired output, with the empty string at the beginning of each row, isn't an option because it has mixed dtypes.  Using only rows `(1,2)` makes this problem irrelevant, since they are both floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the first two columns you could use [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

```
import numpy as np
col1 = np.genfromtxt('yourfile.txt',usecols=(1),delimiter=',',dtype=None)
col2 = np.genfromtxt('yourfile.txt',usecols=(2),delimiter=',',dtype=None)
```

or both together:

```
np.genfromtxt('yourfile.txt',usecols=(1,2),delimiter=',',dtype=None)
```

Comment: Using `genfromtxt` is necessary when there are missing values in the data. Here `loadtxt` works fine.

Answer (score 12):

Check [NumPy's](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) documentation.

```
x, y = np.loadtxt(c, delimiter=',', usecols=(1, 2), unpack=True)
```

The `usecols` parameter should get your job done.

Comment: This is the best answer, but with `usecols=(1, 2)` to match OP's request.

Answer (score 1):

Your "mistake" is that you set your own dtype. If you don't want the dtype you've set (where I see no reason why you wouldn't want it), you can use skiprows and usecols parameters of np.loadtxt() to ONLY load the columns you wish.

Your result will be a NumPy array with a shape of (n, 2), not (n, 3) that you thought you'd have (where n is your number of rows).